# How to check if Product Attribute is equal to

Tags: magento2

**Brief**

On a Product Page, I want to check if a Product Attribute is equal to a specific value. And then output the appropriate text.

**Where I'm at so far**

```
<?php
// Helper for Checking Product Attribute
$_product = $block->getProduct();
// Get Product Attributes
$shape = $_product->getShape();
?>

<!-- Shape Check -->
<?php if ($shape == 'Round'): ?>
    <div>
        <span>I am Round</span>
    </div>
<?php elseif ($shape == 'Square'): ?>
    <div>
        <span>I am Square</span>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div>
        <span>Else</span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Issue**

Despite checking a product that is either **Square** or **Round**, the output only displays **Else**. Therefore, my code isn't checking the attribute correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the attribute type.  For example if it's a dropdown you will get the ID.

Take a look at this for example

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51378438/get-dropdown-attribute-text-magento-2

Try this:

`$shape = $_product->getAttributeText('shape');`